# coalesce function to fill date (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, coalesce

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    M_DATE    SPEND  M_CLIENT     M_SHOW    ACQ   SP_DATE     A_DATE
    ------    ------   ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
    01/02/15  2000     1      GAME       NULL    01/02/15   NULL
    01/03/15  NULL     1      GAME       3       NULL       01/03/15
    01/04/15  NULL     1      GAME       6       NULL       01/04/15
    02/04/15  3000     2      BOOK       NULL    02/04/15   NULL
    02/05/15  NULL     2      BOOK       5       NULL       02/05/15
```

EDIT: I would like to replace the nulls in the cost_date column with the most recent non-null cost_date for a given ID and type.

Ideally, the resulting table would look like this:

```
    M_DATE    SPEND  M_CLIENT     M_SHOW    ACQ   SP_DATE     A_DATE
    ------    ------   ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
    01/02/15  2000     1      GAME       NULL    01/02/15   NULL
    01/03/15  NULL     1      GAME       3       01/02/15   01/03/15
    01/04/15  NULL     1      GAME       6       01/02/15   01/04/15
    02/04/15  3000     2      BOOK       NULL    02/04/15   NULL
    02/05/15  NULL     2      BOOK       5       02/04/15   02/05/15
```

I am currently attempting to do a self join and coalesce cost_date on itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to update your table or create a view?

Comment: I want to create a view

Comment: The issue is that we have test sale dates that occur before cost dates, and we want to filter those out.

Comment: But isn't the cost_date always NULL on these test_sale_dates? Can't you just filter that?

Comment: Yeah but the dates occur before the cost date, so we will have units_sold rows occurring  on dates before sale_date, because those were test dates.

Comment: I'm confused, but ok ;) How do you know which date to set the COST_DATE to? Will there always be only one row per ID with a cost NOT NULL which will hold the COST_DATE to set the other rows to?

Comment: Yeah, so the cost_date is determined by the date at which the cost column is not null.

Comment: Please provide the tables schema definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the LEAD function: lead(sp_date)OVER(PARTITION BY m_client, m_TYPE ORDER BY sp_date) AS next_date

The results:

```
M_DATE    SPEND  M_CLIENT  M_TYPE    ACQ   SP_DATE   next_date
------    ------   ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
01/02/15  2000     1      GAME       NULL    01/02/15   02/04/15
01/03/15  NULL     1      GAME       3       NULL         NULL
01/04/15  NULL     1      GAME       6       NULL         NULL
02/04/15  3000     1      GAME       3       02/04/15     NULL
02/05/15  NULL     2      BOOK       5       01/02/15     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no PostgreSQL access to validate, but something like this should work:

Make a query containing the dates to set to:

```
SELECT id, cost_date
FROM tblName
WHERE cost is not null
```

Make it a view or a subselect to join it onto your table via id, then coalesce as you intended

Comment: Thanks! But the issue with doing that is we want to keep the rows that have null spend values, and fill the blank cost_dates with the cost_date for that particular ID and type, so that later on in the query we can only select WHERE sale_date > cost_date, to get rid of the test rows containing values for units_sold, but with a date that is older than the cost_date.

Comment: You are not losing any rows when joining the query onto your table via id.